# how to generify ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

IDE tells me it is not so good to create array list without generification, and i can not create abstract class Parser and inherit from it, because SAXBooksParser is already extends DefaultHandler, what should i do? leave it like that?

```
    DOMBooksParser domBooksParser = new DOMBooksParser();
    SAXBooksParser saxBooksParser = new SAXBooksParser();
    StAXBooksParser staxBooksParser = new StAXBooksParser();

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(domBooksParser);
    list.add(saxBooksParser);
    list.add(staxBooksParser);
```

Comment: Try with List<? extends BaseClass> list ...

Comment: Do `DOMBooksParser`, `SAXBooksParser` and `StAXBooksParser` have a common base class, like maybe `BaseParser`, and/or interface `Parser` or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*i can not create abstract class Parser and inherit from it, because SAXBooksParser is already extends DefaultHandler* .Create a interface. Make all your classes implement that interface, then use

```
List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<MyInterface>(); // code to the interface. Not to the concrete class.
```

This will still preserve the contract that specifies that your `List` should contain only those 3 classes.

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface BaseParser {}

public DOMBooksParser implements BaseParser
{
//code
}

public SAXBooksParser implements BaseParser
{
//code
}

List<BaseParser> list = new ArrayList<BaseParser>(); //Java 6
List<BaseParser> list = new ArrayList<>(); //Java 7

 DOMBooksParser domBooksParser = new DOMBooksParser();
 SAXBooksParser saxBooksParser = new SAXBooksParser();

 list.add(domBooksParser);
 list.add(saxBooksParser);
```